# How can I get the call duration of any call in a web application using asterisk?

Tags: php, asterisk

I have done a Web site using php and which asterisk is used as a Voip system.Now the problem is I want to get the call duration of each call after 'HANG UP'.I googled alot and got an asterisk variable named ${ANSWEREDTIME},but don't know how I can get the value from it and how I can initiate it.
Please Help and consider me as new bee to PHP AGI scripting...!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the database has a billsec field which I believe is the call length

Comment: Yes I know that there is a field in it.I have also checked it in the log file of the table CDR.But it is returning an empty set after the Hang Up of any of the call done through asterisk.Please help !